# how can I select the month part only in a DATE datatype column using CI active record?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

**How could I select the month part only in a DATE data-type column using CodeIgniter's active record class? What would be my query?

I'm also confused what do i need to use,.. LIKE or WHERE clause?

here is my model code snippet.**

```
`$previousMonth = date('m', strtotime(date('Y-m')." -1 month"));
$where = "MONTH(post_created_at),$previousMonth";
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_post');
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->where('post_approve', 'Yes');
$this->db->where('post_deleted', 'No');
$query=$this->db->get();
$countvalue = $query->num_rows();
echo "print_r($countvalue,TRUE);`
```

Comment: this may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12256151/1978142 http://stackoverflow.com/a/17968278/1978142

Answer (score 0):

Well. WHERE is used if you want to select one row from the table. LIKE is used when you want more results than 2.

For example:

`SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$inputEmail';`


`SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='$firstName';`

So, the first one you already know that it will return one value. The second returns various results.

You can think how a search engine works, it works with the statement LIKE for get a lot of result, and WHERE is used for logins.